# Using the printlist/1 predicate in Prolog to sum up all numbers in a list

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to use the `printlist/1` predicate to sum up all the numbers in a list but kind of got stuck.... tried to come up with the code for this but I keep getting `false`.

Here is what I've come up with:

```
printlist([]).
printlist([H|T], Totalsum) :- 
   print (H+Totalsum),
   nl,
   printlist(T, Totalsum).
```

I know it's wrong and it's probably the last part. Any help is appreciated!

I query it this way:

```
?- printlist([1,2,3]).
false.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paulo already said, you are defining two predicates here, which is incorrect.

Here is the solution:

```
printlist([], 0).
printlist([H|T], Sum) :-
   printlist(T, Subsum),
   Sum is Subsum + H.
```

Sample query:

```
?- printlist([1,2,3,5], L).
L = 11.
```

@ Paulo requested), a tail recursive version:

```
printlist(L, Sum) :-
   sumac(L, 0, Sum).

sumac([], Acc, Acc).
sumac([H|T], Acc, Sum) :-
   Nacc is Acc + H,
   sumac(T, Nacc, Sum).
```

Comment: Can you follow up with an alternative predicate definition that's *tail recursive*?

Comment: Why use the name `printlist`? It implies the use of side-effects, which, luckily, you do not use. How about renaming the predicate to  `list_sum` or something similar?

Comment: @repeat. indeed, list_sum s better.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining not one but two predicates: `printlist/1` and `printlist/2`. Likely a typo. The `printlist/2` predicate is a recursive rule but there isn't a base case. Change the `printlist/1` clause to:

```
printlist([], _).
```

But there are other errors in your code. Hint: Prolog is not a functional language.

Comment: Do I just leave it at: print(H),nl,printlist(T+Sum1) to recursively call printlist with the tail

Comment: Check what happens if you call e.g. `print(1+2)`.